# flutter audio_service and just_audio not working on ios

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of song on song screen. If user click the one item in the list, I call the loadFirstPlaylist() to load the list of songs(all song in album) into queue and then skip the queue and play. It is working on android but I got following error on iOS.
[GitHub Sources Code](https://github.com/alexaung/musicplayer)
**[NowPlaying] [MRNowPlaying] Ignoring setPlaybackState because application does not contain entitlement com.apple.mediaremote.set-playback-state for platform**

```
Future<void> loadFirstPlayList(List<MediaItem> playlist, int index) async {
    await emptyPlaylist();
    if (playlist.isNotEmpty) {
      await _audioHandler.addQueueItems(playlist);
      await _audioHandler.skipToQueueItem(index);
      await _audioHandler.play();
   }
}
```

Audio Handler Method

```
@override
Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    final audioSource = mediaItems.map(_createAudioSource);
    _playlist.addAll(audioSource.toList());

    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..addAll(mediaItems);
    queue.add(newQueue);
}

@override
Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    if (index < 0 || index >= queue.value.length) return;
    if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
      index = _player.shuffleIndices![index];
    }
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: index);
 }

@override
Future<void> play() => _player.play();
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you have figured it out or not already. However, I had the same issue when trying to load an empty playlist. I was following [this example](https://github.com/suragch/flutter_audio_service_demo/blob/master/final/lib/services/audio_handler.dart), which includes a `_loadEmptyPlaylist` method. However, when I implemented it this caused the player to fail silently. It now seems to be working by not calling `loadAudioSource` on an empty audio sequence.

Comment: I changed and used playlist example in audio_service as based handler and added my other function. It is working fine so far. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @colioli Thank you so much. This fixed my issue. It's weird cause it works with the empty playlist in Android, but it would silently fail on iOS without a single error or exception. OP, you should consider marking this as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @colioli
in this case(do not _loadEmptyPlaylist) how and when you do this line:
await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
???